# Wordpress autologin, database error on multisite

Tags: wordpress, authentication, multisite, autologin, wordpress-login

I'm working on an autologin for Wordpress and everything was working really good, till I enabled my multisite and tried to use it when multisite is off it does its thing logs in and redirects to dashboard, but when I enable it  trows

"Error establishing Database Connection"

What could be causing this?

Does multisite WordPress change the database URL?

Here is the code for you to see.

```
include'../wordpress/wp-load.php';

 $errors = array();

$username = 'admin';
$password = '123456';
$remember =  "true";

$login_data = array();
$login_data['user_login'] = $username;
$login_data['user_password'] = $password;
$login_data['remember'] = $remember;
$user_verify = wp_signon($login_data, true);

    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->ID);

    wp_redirect(admin_url());

    exit;
```

Comment: Your question needs a little more context - is this being used in a plugin? Or a theme file?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it's being used from an external folder into the same server that hosts the wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

The database connection error message "Error establishing Database Connection" is a message from the `wpdb::db_connect()` class method.  If the method didn't properly handle the connection, this error is thrown.

Turn on WP_DEBUG in your wp-config.php file to output more information to the screen.  That should give you information on why the database is not connecting by outputting errors from PHP's `mysqli_connect()` (which is what is being used to connect to the db).

Comment: Sorry, i enabled debug and still get no specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking it up i realized two things

**1: the error came from wp-load.php**

**2: as i thought it was because the file was taking current url as database url**

so in fixed it doing this

Go to >  wp-includes/ms-load.php

Look for  ms_load_current_site_and_network() function
 and just afther the function  starts set the $path variable to your url this way

since my wordpress install was  a local one

my url was localhost/wordpress

the system already gets "localhost" the rest of my url is "wordpress"

so path must contain "wordpress"

the function now looks like this

```
function ms_load_current_site_and_network( $domain, $path, $subdomain = false ) {

//THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
    $path="wordpress";
//THIS IS THE END OF  WHAT I ADDED

    global $current_site, $current_blog;

    // If the network is defined in wp-config.php, we can simply use that.
    if ( defined( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE' ) && defined( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE' ) ) {
        $current_site = new stdClass;
        $current_site->id = defined( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE' ) ? SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE : 1;
        $current_site->domain = DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE;
        $current_site->path = PATH_CURRENT_SITE;
        if ( defined( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE' ) ) {
            $current_site->blog_id = BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE;
        } elseif ( defined( 'BLOGID_CURRENT_SITE' ) ) { // deprecated.
            $current_site->blog_id = BLOGID_CURRENT_SITE;
        }

        if ( 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->domain, $domain ) && 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->path, $path ) ) {
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path );
        } elseif ( '/' !== $current_site->path && 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->domain, $domain ) && 0 === stripos( $path, $current_site->path ) ) {
            // If the current network has a path and also matches the domain and path of the request,
            // we need to look for a site using the first path segment following the network's path.
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 + count( explode( '/', trim( $current_site->path, '/' ) ) ) );
        } else {
            // Otherwise, use the first path segment (as usual).
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 );
        }

    } elseif ( ! $subdomain ) {
        /*
         * A "subdomain" installation can be re-interpreted to mean "can support any domain".
         * If we're not dealing with one of these installations, then the important part is determining
         * the network first, because we need the network's path to identify any sites.
         */
        if ( ! $current_site = wp_cache_get( 'current_network', 'site-options' ) ) {
            // Are there even two networks installed?
            $networks = get_networks( array( 'number' => 2 ) );
            if ( count( $networks ) === 1 ) {
                $current_site = array_shift( $networks );
                wp_cache_add( 'current_network', $current_site, 'site-options' );
            } elseif ( empty( $networks ) ) {
                // A network not found hook should fire here.
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ( empty( $current_site ) ) {
            $current_site = WP_Network::get_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 );
        }

        if ( empty( $current_site ) ) {
            /**
             * Fires when a network cannot be found based on the requested domain and path.
             *
             * At the time of this action, the only recourse is to redirect somewhere
             * and exit. If you want to declare a particular network, do so earlier.
             *
             * @since 4.4.0
             *
             * @param string $domain       The domain used to search for a network.
             * @param string $path         The path used to search for a path.
             */
            do_action( 'ms_network_not_found', $domain, $path );

            return false;
        } elseif ( $path === $current_site->path ) {
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path );
        } else {
            // Search the network path + one more path segment (on top of the network path).
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, substr_count( $current_site->path, '/' ) );
        }
    } else {
        // Find the site by the domain and at most the first path segment.
        $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 );
        if ( $current_blog ) {
            $current_site = WP_Network::get_instance( $current_blog->site_id ? $current_blog->site_id : 1 );
        } else {
            // If you don't have a site with the same domain/path as a network, you're pretty screwed, but:
            $current_site = WP_Network::get_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 );
        }
    }

    // The network declared by the site trumps any constants.
    if ( $current_blog && $current_blog->site_id != $current_site->id ) {
        $current_site = WP_Network::get_instance( $current_blog->site_id );
    }

    // No network has been found, bail.
    if ( empty( $current_site ) ) {
        /** This action is documented in wp-includes/ms-settings.php */
        do_action( 'ms_network_not_found', $domain, $path );

        return false;
    }

    // During activation of a new subdomain, the requested site does not yet exist.
    if ( empty( $current_blog ) && wp_installing() ) {
        $current_blog = new stdClass;
        $current_blog->blog_id = $blog_id = 1;
        $current_blog->public = 1;
    }

    // No site has been found, bail.
    if ( empty( $current_blog ) ) {
        // We're going to redirect to the network URL, with some possible modifications.
        $scheme = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
        $destination = "$scheme://{$current_site->domain}{$current_site->path}";

        /**
         * Fires when a network can be determined but a site cannot.
         *
         * At the time of this action, the only recourse is to redirect somewhere
         * and exit. If you want to declare a particular site, do so earlier.
         *
         * @since 3.9.0
         *
         * @param object $current_site The network that had been determined.
         * @param string $domain       The domain used to search for a site.
         * @param string $path         The path used to search for a site.
         */
        do_action( 'ms_site_not_found', $current_site, $domain, $path );

        if ( $subdomain && ! defined( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT' ) ) {
            // For a "subdomain" installation, redirect to the signup form specifically.
            $destination .= 'wp-signup.php?new=' . str_replace( '.' . $current_site->domain, '', $domain );
        } elseif ( $subdomain ) {
            // For a "subdomain" installation, the NOBLOGREDIRECT constant
            // can be used to avoid a redirect to the signup form.
            // Using the ms_site_not_found action is preferred to the constant.
            if ( '%siteurl%' !== NOBLOGREDIRECT ) {
                $destination = NOBLOGREDIRECT;
            }
        } elseif ( 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->domain, $domain ) ) {
            /*
             * If the domain we were searching for matches the network's domain,
             * it's no use redirecting back to ourselves -- it'll cause a loop.
             * As we couldn't find a site, we're simply not installed.
             */
            return false;
        }

        return $destination;
    }

    // Figure out the current network's main site.
    if ( empty( $current_site->blog_id ) ) {
        $current_site->blog_id = get_main_site_id( $current_site->id );
    }

    return true;
}
```

then i run my login.php file and it worked!!!

hope it helps